# Do I need to install a Resource Manager Tool In Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I recently started using Android Studio with Flutter for basic App Development. I can't find the Resource Manager anywhere, expect one place. When i Right-Click on `android/app/src/main/res` an option called "Show In Resource Manager" appears and is clickable, but when i Right-Click on it nothing happens.

Do I need to Install this tool separately, or do I have to enable it somewhere in Android Studio?

Comment: Please ask a question only once. Only because you didn't like the answer, this here is still a dupe.

Comment: I understand.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you've opened the project at the wrong directory level.

Just close the IDE and then open `android` as a project.

Also see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager).